# Can I leave my dead infected dwellers in my vault and slowly revive them back by caps?

Tags: fallout-shelter

All 52 of my dwellers are radiated and dead. I don't have enough RadAways and Stimpaks to cure them. Can I leave them there and slowly revive them once I have enough caps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dead dwellers disappear after 24 hours, so if you can raise enough caps to revive a large amount of them at once in less than a day, then it may be worthwhile. Just keep in mind that dwellers are very unhappy when they are around corpses. Reviving 52 dwellers would be a LOT of caps though, as they get more expensive the higher the level.

Comment: Right answer. Just let the smaller levels die, revive just the higher ones or the ones with better equipment.

Comment: If the dead dwellers disappear, the suit and the weapon they are wearing are gone as well?